# how can i do this by using only one xml tag

Tags: android, xml

i what to do this by using one XML tag

i will tried image inside text view with draw able left property
butt its does not work

```
 <TextView
       android:id="@+id/alert"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:drawableBottom="@drawable/alertlogo"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/Alert"
       />
```

[i want to this by using one XML tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECiPA.png)

Comment: That's not a great image. Please [edit] your question to describe, in words, exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/alert"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/alertlogo"
       android:text="@string/Alert"
       />
```

You can use drawablePadding to set padding of your image and it's better to use android assets images for drawable images.